# Which condition should $b$ satisfy in order to make the inequality $|a-b|^2\le |a|^2$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inequality, vectors

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be two nonnull vectors. Assume that $|a|\le 1$.
Which are the vectors $b$ such that the inequality
$$|a-b|^2\le |a|^2$$
holds true?

I was trying to find them just using the definition so that
$$|a-b|^2\le |a|^2 \iff (a_1-b_1)^2 + (a_2-b_2)^2+(a_3-b_3)^2\le a_1^2 + a_2^2 +a_3^2$$

but it seems not easy to me to find a condition from that.

Do someone have a better idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you just drop the squares here since both sides being squared are already positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometrically this just means that the distance from $a$ to $b$ cannot be greater than the distance from $a$ to the origin. So if you visualize a sphere centered on $a$ with radius equal to the distance between $a$ and the origin, then $b$ must be inside it. I don't think you will find any interesting conditions involving the individual coordinates themselves.

So at the risk of being vacuous, the condition that $b$ should satisfy is... $|a - b| \leq |a|$.